# CoffeeScript function for Jasmine testing - parenthesis are weird

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I got my first test working in plain JavaScript and then I wanted to try writing the same test in CoffeeScript.

The parenthesis are not coming out the way I want, which is causing the test to fail... The error I'm getting is: `TypeError: Object 1.00 has no method 'toBe'`

My working JavaScript test is as follows:

```
describe( "conversion from water to coffee", function () {  
  it("converts water to coffee", function () {  
    expect(waterToCoffeeCalc(17)).toBe('1.00');  
  }); 
});
```

My CoffeeScript version is:

```
describe "coversion from water to coffee", ->
  it "coverts water to coffee", ->
    expect (waterToCoffeeCalc 17).toBe('1.00')
```

This CoffeeScript is compiling to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
describe("coversion from water to coffee", function() {
  return it("coverts water to coffee", function() {
    return expect((waterToCoffeeCalc(17)).toBe('1.00'));
  });
});
```

I see the problem with the parenthesis, but I'm just learning CoffeeScript and I'm not sure the correct way to pass my argument to my function.

Comment: Try: `expect(waterToCofeeCalc 17).toBe '1.00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoffeeScript is very sensitive to whitespace. This:

```
f(x).g()
```

is parsed the same as it is in JavaScript: no space means that the parentheses in `f(x)` are "function invoking" parentheses. This:

```
f (x).g()
```

however, is parsed as:

```
f((x).g())
```

so a space means that the parentheses in `f (x)` are "expression grouping" parentheses. That space between the method name and its arguments completely changes the meaning of the code.

You probably want to say this:

```
expect(waterToCoffeeCalc 17).toBe('1.00')
```

or even:

```
expect(waterToCoffeeCalc(17)).toBe('1.00')
```

The rule of thumb is to never put a space between the function name (or `if` for that matter) and its parenthesized arguments.